# Plotting 17 columns gives plot.new() error figure margins too large

Tags: r, plot, par

I have 17 columns (16 predictors and 1 target class) and 80 observations.

## sample dataset

```
colA,colB,colC,colD,colE,colF,colG,colH,colI,colJ,colK,colL,colM,colN,colO,colP,colQ
88.0,79.0,75.0,81.0,45.0,68.0,47.0,57.0,68.0,52.0,66.0,61.0,64.0,64.0,58.0,51.0,60
80.0,91.0,69.0,70.0,35.0,68.0,58.0,50.0,55.0,48.0,49.0,66.0,45.0,45.0,59.0,78.0,62
87.0,68.0,78.0,96.0,67.0,57.0,85.0,77.0,76.0,88.0,75.0,67.0,50.0,50.0,74.0,79.0,62
85.0,90.0,64.0,73.0,45.0,75.0,42.0,63.0,59.0,69.0,52.0,48.0,77.0,77.0,71.0,57.0,67
57.0,54.0,46.0,41.0,35.0,53.0,29.0,52.0,43.0,49.0,41.0,51.0,47.0,47.0,54.0,53.0,58
82.0,89.0,60.0,99.0,44.0,68.0,60.0,84.0,72.0,80.0,64.0,49.0,64.0,64.0,57.0,72.0,67
73.0,90.0,76.0,82.0,48.0,73.0,56.0,66.0,66.0,55.0,60.0,48.0,61.0,61.0,68.0,73.0,69
84.0,84.0,76.0,90.0,53.0,47.0,44.0,40.0,51.0,38.0,55.0,37.0,58.0,58.0,61.0,66.0,67
56.0,59.0,55.0,48.0,51.0,62.0,22.0,87.0,62.0,47.0,77.0,69.0,41.0,41.0,51.0,66.0,56
84.0,80.0,68.0,79.0,37.0,51.0,72.0,70.0,62.0,60.0,53.0,45.0,65.0,65.0,69.0,66.0,67
92.0,73.0,89.0,78.0,60.0,68.0,72.0,80.0,95.0,60.0,83.0,87.0,78.0,78.0,47.0,94.0,66
94.0,82.0,79.0,99.0,67.0,71.0,79.0,92.0,91.0,87.0,58.0,72.0,73.0,73.0,76.0,71.0,71
90.0,74.0,73.0,84.0,59.0,69.0,74.0,83.0,59.0,60.0,71.0,71.0,65.0,65.0,56.0,85.0,75
91.0,78.0,67.0,82.0,71.0,59.0,82.0,89.0,55.0,82.0,72.0,80.0,79.0,79.0,78.0,87.0,80

plot(data)
```

gives error :

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

I tried

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
par(mar =c(2, 2, 2, 2))
plot(data)
```

But no luck. I still get the same error. I am new to par() function. never used before I don't know how to adjust that to fix the error.

I checked in other forums, it says to use : `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))` and change the values to suit your needs.

Comment: Increase the size of your graphics device, you're getting the error because there is not enough space to plot all the panels (since you have many columns). Setting `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` will only make matters worse. Setting `mar` to small values may help.

Comment: How can I go smaller than 1,1,1,1 ? I tried par(mar =c(1, 1, 1, 1)) and didnt seem to work? you mean decimal points?

Comment: @Axeman Can you please tell what would be the reasonable values for: par(mfrow=c(?, ?))
par(mar =c(?, ?, ?, ?)) for 17 columns

Comment: That depends on the size of your graphics device. Increasing that is usually the better option. Set `par(mfrow = c(1, 1))` though.

Comment: @Axeman I set everything to 1 for both mfrow and mar but I get the same error.

Comment: If you think the figure should fit a normal screen and you're using RStudio, consider increasing the size of the panel which holds the Plot tab.

Comment: And just so it's clear since you've been ignoring it and it's been said three times already: The solution is to increase the size of your graphics device. If you're using RStudio then you need to click and drag to make the plot tab actually larger on your screen.

Comment: We do not know what OS your are using so we cannot offer code for your interactive device but you surely could use `png()` or `pdf()`, The `par` funciton is not where you set the parameters for graphics devices. Read `?Devices`. (I don't get that error, although I didn't find the resulting plot particularly meaningful.)

Comment: I am using windows laptop 15 inches and I tried to plot them as pdf. It seemed quite huge and wouldnt fit in Rstudio plot tab or in separate window in anyway. It worked using pdf thanks alot